# What's the expected behavior of a dependent app when an LDAP user's DN changes?

Tags: ldap

Is there any expected/standardized behavior for an app that authenticates via LDAP, when one of its registered users has its DN changed? (Or more generally, when their effective principal changes, which seems to commonly be their DN. I'll say "principal" instead from here, though I usually think "DN".)

Here's an example from Gitlab running into this issue: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-foss/issues/993

In their case (based on the [commit](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-foss/commit/89bdcc60177d760ddd3b2f88a6e52319e5035d64) linked in that issue) they seem to address this by using multiple attributes to identify users instead of a single one, so that a single change doesn't prevent them from mapping back to the same LDAP user.

It seems to me the available options would be:

1. Don't try to prevent the issue but provide some method to change the principal stored (either in-app or via DB modifications)
2. Try to prevent the issue by picking (automatically or manually by user) a better, static user attribute to use as principal
3. Try to mitigate the issue by cross-referencing multiple attributes, as in the above links

Which of these would be the expected/"best" approach here, if any?

Comment: It depends on your configuration, on what has changed in the dn, and whether these changes affect all users or not. Edit your post : add your current configuration and the dn before/after modification.

Comment: This isn't an internal tool so I can't guarantee what DNs or attributes our customers might use. Any "example" configuration would therefore be moot in this discussion (which is meant to be general anyway)

It sounds like there is no answer, which is obnoxious for anyone making software authenticating through LDAP

Comment: You may not know what exact dn a user might use, but still you should know which ldap attribute you want to use for authentication and under which base should be located user entries in the target directory. If you haven't any base configuration, you probably have some requirements and a server config that can be translated into a working gitlab-ldap config, otherwise I don't see how you could get any answer..